# Who makes this kitchen faucet handle (logo identification)?

Tags: faucet

**Who makes this kitchen faucet handle (logo identification)?**

It is broken and I can't seem to remove/uninstall the faucet. Does anyone recognize this logo or know how I might go about finding the answer myself?

I've done image searches and I can't find any helpful information.

[image: kitchen faucet logo]

Resampled logo: [image]

Comment: Maybe include some pictures of the base of the faucet mount, and the underside of the mount. I've seen folks here be able to figure out how to get them disassembled without knowing who made it or having a manual handy.

Comment: "*I can't seem to remove/uninstall the faucet*"  Have you looked at the bottom of the faucet under the sink to see how it is attached?

Comment: please post a closeup of the logo, oriented properly ... use the picture to do google image search

Comment: https://www.sunrisespecialty.com/how-to-identify-kitchen-faucet-brand

Comment: Funny thing is, I found the logo being used as a template at a graphics design reseller. So either somebody "acquired" the plumbing logo for a graphic design service, or somebody used the generic logo place-holder for their plumbing products....  https://img.tineye.com/result/8134592fff7d05af050eb59d2e46e478b4476dfd306489df1da0ed31a16163fc?size=160

Comment: Why not just show us the faucet. Chances are we can help with the _actual_ problem.